# Azure file shared access signature expires before end date

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

I am using the Azure 12 month trial account and hosting an excel file on the Storage account through Azure Portal.

I generate a Shared access signature with End date as three months from today and affix the generated SAS token to the File's URL.

I am able to access the file using this process. However, the token quickly expires after some invocations of the URL. The issue was most recently observed after overwriting the file with an updated file on Azure storage account, followed by regenerating the SAS token.

The URL with SAS token suffixed to it looks like:

```
https://xxxxxx.file.core.windows.net/folder_name/yyyyy.xlsx?sv=2019-02-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2019-12-30T16:04:08Z&st=2019-10-22T08:04:08Z&spr=https,http&sig=xxxxx%yyyyy%zzzz
```

Here is the error I see:

```
<Error>
<Code>ConditionHeadersNotSupported</Code>
<Message>
Condition headers are not supported. RequestId:<XXXXX> Time:<YYYYYY>
</Message>
</Error>
```

The error is random and the URL works intermittently.

Has anyone observed this issue and what could be a fix?

Comment: Which method did you use to overwrite it?

Comment: I manually uploaded the updated file to Azure portal. Then from Home > Storage accounts > Shared access signature I regenerated the SAS token.

Comment: What is the basis for your judgment of SAS token expiration?

Comment: Can you describe your problem more clearly, such as providing some screenshots without revealing privacy?

Comment: @BowmanZhu Sure. I added the relevant detail with all token identifiers and filenames cleansed. Question Edit done.

Comment: @stackoverflowN Your SAS token is not expired. I suggest you to Use Azure Blob Storage. That can avoid this problem.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-file#request-headers file Storage does not support `if` header.

Comment: Please describe how you're using the SAS URL.

Comment: @stackoverflowN Can you work it out now?(upload to Azure blob Storage), I have provided a link to you, It describles how to upload from local path.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your error.

[image]

This does not mean that the SAS token has been expired. Because if you test the Azure Blob Storage, everything will be ok. Error comes from the browser we are using know. The browser  add the `if condition` header.

[image]

When there is no `if` header, you can use it normally.

[image]

That is because File Storage does not support `if` header. And the request which has `if` header will not be accepted by File Storage.

This is the [Offical doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-file#request-headers) about what kind of header that the File Storage support.

So it is not the responsibility of SAS token. It is a fault about the browser. If it is not special, I suggest you use Azure Blob Storage, it will not cause problems.

Comment: The behavior of the browser adding the `if` header is not certain, you can try to enter the full url in the new page or refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks! I understand now why the URL cannot be reliably fetched from the browser. I am using the browser as a test. In my project I am trying to fetch the file in C# using DownloadData() method of System.Net.WebClient. I see the same intermittent behavior there.

Is it the same underlying reason for the error in WebClient.DownloadData() method and if so, is there an alternative method such as DownloadToStream() that I could use if this file were to be uploaded as a Blob?

Comment: @stackoverflowN Do you want to upload files from local file path?

Comment: @stackoverflowN Hi,take a look of this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#upload-blobs-to-a-container

Comment: Is this method you need?

Comment: @stackoverflowN Have any other doubt? If my solution solve your problem, can you mark it as the answer of this question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is due to Microsoft's Windows-Azure-File/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 set up.

The service hasn't been designed primarily for browsers to access files, and is limited in what headers it supports.

Browsers will typically look at the local cached copied of files before attempting to download a new copy.  They do this by examining the local file attributes and asking the web server to give them the file "IF" it has been modified after the date corresponding to the cache through the use of the **If-Modified-Since** header, just as BowmanZhu said.

Instead of ignoring the header, the server is throwing an error.  To overcome this, you need to perform a hard reload of the page.  In Chrome, you can do this by pressing **CTRL + SHIFT + R**.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to access the method using C# WebClient.DownloadData() method and I see the intermittent error there too. Have asked question above to check if it is the same underlying cause and would an alternate method such as DownloadToStream() would resolve the problem?

Comment: The WebClient class uses Internet Explorer cache.  DownloadData() may work, but unless you're stuck using WebClient I'd use the HttpRequest class instead.  If this doesn't solve it then consider your infrastructure and whether your path to the storage account goes via a proxy server as proxies often have their own caching mechanisms and may be inserting the if header.